# Sql server 2005 and windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7

I have the symptoms in this articles, but I have Windows 7 32 bit, and "Group Policy Management Console" dos not work install due to compatibility problem so I can't follow the tutorial. Can you help me running SQL server 2005 ?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941823

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define the group policy on a domain controller, and filter the GPO so that it only affects your machine.

If you aren't in a domain you can't do this as GPOs are only available when your computer is a member of a Windows 2000 or higher domain.